# Python QT dropdown list signal changes too often and not once

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have Python 3.9 with PyQt5 5.15.4.

In QT designer, I created a drop down list. In the initialization code, I filled it with the following values:

```
self.MEMSDropDown.addItems(["Select MEMS" ])
MEMS_avail = ['MEMS_1' , 'MEMS_2' , 'MEMS_3' , 'MEMS_4' , 'MEMS_5' , 'MEMS_6' ]
self.MEMSDropDown.addItems(MEMS_avail)
```

Then, I do the Signals / Callback connection:

```
self.MEMSDropDown.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.Changed__MEMSDropDown)
```

Then, in the function "Changed__MEMSDropDown", I have written:

```
#self.blockSignals(True)
def Changed__MEMSDropDown(self, i):
self.MEMSDropDown.clear()
print("'Changed__MEMSDropDown' function is called now.")
#self.blockSignals(False)
```

My problem is now, this function is called TWICE, or, if instead I use "clear" I add more items to the dropdown list, this is seems to be called iteratively again, e.g. 7 times, if I add with the function "self.MEMSDropDown.addItems(MEMS_avail)".

BUT: I want that it is changed only ONCE when I select another item with the mouse. I do not want that this function is called when I add or remove items programatically. I have tried over "block signals", as commented-out now above, but if I comment them in, the program just crashes.

So the program should behave: As soon as the "Changed__MEMSDropDown" is called, it should remove the entry "Select MEMS" from the item list and keep the rest.

What can I do, that the function is called only once, and not multiple times?

Thanks a lot!

See above. P.S.: I am completely new to Python and to QT.

Comment: TYPO: move `self.blockSignals(True)` inside the function.

Comment: Yes, correct, this was just a copy/paste error. However, I solved it: It works with: "self.MEMSDropDown.blockSignals(True)" and False.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: It works with: "self.MEMSDropDown.blockSignals(True)" and False.

Comment: Better: use [QSignalBlocker(target)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html): `with QSignalBlocker(self.MEMSDropDown):` `self.MEMSDropDown.clear()`. Alternatively, depending on the situation, temporarily disconnect the signal from the function, do whatever you need, and reconnect it again; this approach is useful whenever the signal is connected to other functions and you just want to avoid recursion within a specific function, while keeping the other working as usual.